# Nested Layouts inside Linear Layout (vertical) - Ensuring the last nested layout displays its contents

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linear-layout (vertically-oriented) that contains two nested linear layouts inside of it.

- The first linear-layout has a background image that is applied dynamically based on the context o the particular activity. The image pretty much takes up the whole size of the screen
- The second linear-layout contains two checkboxes (horizontally-oriented) that should be displayed at the bottom of the activity.

My question is, how can I ensure that the second linear-layout displays at the bottom of the screen and just shows the minimal amount it needs to, allowing the first linear-layout to display as much as its background image as possible? Currently it's being pushed off the screen by the first LL's bg image.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Weight you can do what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >



    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CheckBox" />
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CheckBox" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *RelativeLayout* as the outer layout instead of *LinearLayout*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/topLayout"
         android:layout_above="@id/bottomLayout"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    ... >
    <LinearLayout
        ...
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        ...
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Notice on the  weighted layout, the height is set to "0dp". With only one weighted, the weighted one will stretch to fit the rest of the available area.